# FATAL EXCEPTION: main & NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I've been looking around several hours for a solution. I'm trying to build a BodyMassIndex calculator. I have finished the program (i think) but every time I try to run the app, it crashes on the emulator. On top of that, the layout preview isn't showing up anymore. I'm still trying to learn what all of the error codes in the log mean. I think it's a problem with my layout.xml, but I'm not sure. Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

**Logcat**:

```
03-06 06:04:56.533: W/Trace(969): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-06 06:04:56.533: W/Trace(969): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-06 06:04:56.533: W/Trace(969): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-06 06:04:56.853: W/Trace(969): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-06 06:04:56.853: W/Trace(969): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-06 06:04:57.623: W/Trace(969): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-06 06:04:57.623: W/Trace(969): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-06 06:04:57.633: W/Trace(969): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-06 06:04:57.673: W/Trace(969): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-06 06:04:57.673: W/Trace(969): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-06 06:04:57.683: D/AndroidRuntime(969): Shutting down VM
03-06 06:04:57.683: W/dalvikvm(969): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.forceUniformHeight(LinearLayout.java:1348)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1336)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.widget.TableRow.onMeasure(TableRow.java:114)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.widget.TableLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableLayout.java:464)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:476)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:439)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-06 06:04:57.703: E/AndroidRuntime(969):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 06:04:57.833: D/dalvikvm(969): GC_CONCURRENT freed 155K, 10% free 2670K/2944K, paused 16ms+3ms, total 139ms
```

**Java code**:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BMICalc extends Activity {

    // Constants Used when saving/restoring state.
    private static final String FEET_OF_HEIGHT = "FEET_OF_HEIGHT";
    private static final String INCH_OF_HEIGHT = "INCH_OF_HEIGHT";
    private static final String WEIGHT_IN_LBS = "WEIGHT_IN_LBS";

    private int currentFeetPortionOfHeight;         // Feet portion of height.
    private int currentInchesPortionOfHeight;       // Inches portion of height.
    private double currentWeight;                   // Weight of user in pounds.
    private EditText feetPortionOfHeightEditText;   // Displays feet portion of height.
    private EditText inchesPortionOfHeightEditText; // Displays inches portion of height.
    private EditText weightEditText;                // Displays weight of user.
    private Button calculateButton;                 // Button that starts calculation.
    private TextView bmiResultTextView;             // Displays BMI value.
    private TextView bmiResultCommentsTextView;     // Displays comment on user's BMI result.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmicalc);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {   // If the application just started...
            currentFeetPortionOfHeight = 0;     // Initialize the feet portion to 0.
            currentInchesPortionOfHeight = 0;   // Initialize the inches portion to 0.
            currentWeight = 0.0;                // Initialize the weight to 0.
            // calculateBMI();                  // Calculation for BMI value.

        }
        else {  // Else (the application is being recovered from memory)...
            currentFeetPortionOfHeight = savedInstanceState.getInt(FEET_OF_HEIGHT);     // Initialize the feet portion to saved value.
            currentInchesPortionOfHeight = savedInstanceState.getInt(INCH_OF_HEIGHT);   // Initialize the inches portion to saved value.
            currentWeight = savedInstanceState.getDouble(WEIGHT_IN_LBS);                // Initialize the weight to saved value.
            // calculateBMI();                                                          // Calculation for BMI value.
        }

        // Get references to feet/inches/weight EditTexts.
        feetPortionOfHeightEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.feetPortionOfHeightEditText);
        inchesPortionOfHeightEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inchesPortionOfHeightEditText);
        weightEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightEditText);

        // Get references to TextViews displaying BMI & comment.
        bmiResultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmiResultTextView);
        bmiResultCommentsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmiResultCommentsTextView);

        // Get reference to calculateButton.
        calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);

        // EditText Watchers handle the EditTexts onTextChanged events.
        feetPortionOfHeightEditText.addTextChangedListener(feetPortionOfHeightEditTextWatcher);
        inchesPortionOfHeightEditText.addTextChangedListener(inchesPortionOfHeightEditTextWatcher);
        weightEditText.addTextChangedListener(weightEditTextWatcher);
        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(calculateButtonWatcher);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_bmicalc, menu);
        return true;
    }

    protected void onSavedInstanceState (Bundle outState) {

        // Saves the values of feetPortion.., inchesPortion.., & weightEditText.
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putDouble(FEET_OF_HEIGHT, currentFeetPortionOfHeight);
        outState.putDouble(INCH_OF_HEIGHT, currentInchesPortionOfHeight);
        outState.putDouble(WEIGHT_IN_LBS, currentWeight);
    }

    private void calculateBMI() {

        // Calculates the bmiResult.
        double bmiResult = currentWeight * 703 / 
                Math.pow((currentFeetPortionOfHeight * 12 + currentInchesPortionOfHeight), 2);

        // Sets the bmiResultComment statement based on bmiResult value.
        String bmiResultComment = setBMIResultComment(bmiResult);

        // Sets bmiResultTextView & bmiResultCommentTextView.
        bmiResultTextView.setText(String.format("%.02f", bmiResult));
        bmiResultCommentsTextView.setText(bmiResultComment);
    }

    private String setBMIResultComment (double bmiResult) {
        String bmiResultComment = "";   // Creates & initializes the bmiResult comment statement.

        // Sets the bmiResultComment to appropriate statement.
        if ( bmiResult == 0.0) {

            bmiResultComment = ""; // If BMI is zero, nothing has been entered & nothing needs to be displayed.

        } else if (bmiResult < 18.5) {

            bmiResultComment = "BMI Values under 18.5 are considered to be UNDERWEIGHT!";

        } else if (bmiResult < 24.9) {

            bmiResultComment = "BMI Values between 18.5 and 24.9 are considered to be NORMAL.";

        } else if (bmiResult < 29.9) {

            bmiResultComment = "BMI Values between 24.9 and 29.9 are considered to be OVERWEIGHT!";

        } else {

            bmiResultComment = "BMI Values over 30 are considered to be OBESE!!!";

        }

        return bmiResultComment; // Returns the bmiResultComment string value.
    }

    private OnClickListener calculateButtonWatcher = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View calculateButtonListener) {
            calculateBMI(); // Calculation for BMI value.
        }

    };

    private TextWatcher feetPortionOfHeightEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            try {currentFeetPortionOfHeight = (int) Double.parseDouble( s.toString() );} // Convert currentFeetPortion... to double.
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {currentFeetPortionOfHeight = 0;}            // Default if an exception occurs.
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { /* Intentionally left empty. */ }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) { /* Intentionally left empty. */ }
    };

    private TextWatcher inchesPortionOfHeightEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            try {currentInchesPortionOfHeight = (int) Double.parseDouble( s.toString() );} // Convert currentInchesPortion... to double.
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {currentInchesPortionOfHeight = 0;}          // Default if an exception occurs.
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { /* Intentionally left empty. */ }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) { /* Intentionally left empty. */ }
    };

    private TextWatcher weightEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            try {currentWeight = (int) Double.parseDouble( s.toString() );} // Convert currentWeight to double.
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {currentWeight = 0;}            // Default if an exception occurs.
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { /* Intentionally left empty. */ }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) { /* Intentionally left empty. */ }
    };  

}
```

**Layout XML**:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        tools:context=".BMICalc" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/introductionTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/DodgerBlue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/introductionTextViewPadding"
                android:text="@string/introductionTextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/heightPromptTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5sp"
                android:background="@color/LightGrey"
                android:text="@string/heightPromptTextView" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5sp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/feetPortionOfHeightEditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/feetPortionOfHeightViewText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5sp"
                android:paddingRight="5sp"
                android:text="@string/feetPortionOfHeightTextView" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inchesPortionOfHeightEditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/inchesPortionOfHeightViewText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5sp"
                android:paddingRight="5sp"
                android:text="@string/inchPortionOfHeightTextView" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/weightPromptTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5sp"
                android:background="@color/LightGrey"
                android:text="@string/weightPromptTextView" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:paddingLeft="20sp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/weightEditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:inputType="number" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/weightTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:padding="5sp"
                android:text="@string/weightTextView" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5sp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/calculateButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@color/Navy"
                android:text="@string/calculateButton" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5sp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bmiResultTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/bmiResultsTextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bmiResultCommentsTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/bmiResultCommentsTextView" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: [`NullPointerException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

Answer (score 1):

Remember below about TableLayout.

A layout that arranges its children horizontally. A TableRow should always be used as a child of a TableLayout. If a TableRow's parent is not a TableLayout, the TableRow will behave as an horizontal LinearLayout.

The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.

I used your layout and removed some of the attributes.It is working now. You cna do one thing, try to add the deleted attributes one by one and check the validity using the graphic layout tab.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/introductionTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/heightPromptTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/feetPortionOfHeightEditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/feetPortionOfHeightViewText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inchesPortionOfHeightEditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/inchesPortionOfHeightViewText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5sp"
                android:paddingRight="5sp"
                />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/weightPromptTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                 />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:paddingLeft="20sp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/weightEditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                android:inputType="number" >


            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/weightTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                 />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5sp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/calculateButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5sp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bmiResultTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bmiResultCommentsTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                 />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem in the layout file. Spans Error and child height of table row.
Try using this xml. Just copy paste the same from table row0, It should work.

```
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/introductionTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="introductionTextView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heightPromptTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:background="#aaaaaa"
            android:text="heightPromptTextView" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5sp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/feetPortionOfHeightEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/feetPortionOfHeightViewText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:paddingRight="5sp"
            android:text="feetPortionOfHeightTextView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inchesPortionOfHeightEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inchesPortionOfHeightViewText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:paddingRight="5sp"
            android:text="inchPortionOfHeightTextView" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weightPromptTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:background="#aaaaaa"
            android:text="weightPromptTextView" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:paddingLeft="20sp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/weightEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weightTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:text="weightTextView" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5sp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calculateButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:text="calculateButton" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5sp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bmiResultTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="bmiResultsTextView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bmiResultCommentsTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="bmiResultCommentsTextView" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you guys so much! That did the trick. Now I just have to get the key board to pop up when you click an EditText.